# Mapbox-gl full screen hides components behind

Tags: fullscreen, mapbox-gl-js

I have a React component that uses mapbox gl...This component returns couple of my own React components that typically render on top of mapbbox-gl map. But, when I use fullscreeen control to go to fullscreen mode, all those components get hidden behind mapbox gl map

Comment: I'm looking for an answer for this too

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that the built in mapbox control is using the HTML5 fullscreen api:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fullscreen_API

Which targets a specific element to bring to the forefront. I don't think there's any way around this. I think perhaps a custom control that called fullscreen on a wrapper container around whatever elements you want to include in the fullscreen view would be the way to go-